# This is not valid housing

Tags: terraria

What's going on here?

It was previously occupied, but they all moved out and now they wont go back. I haven't touched it.

[image: HELP!]

I'm on PC latest update. I tried replacing the table and chair and the blocks! If anyone else has this problem please tell me how you fixed it or if its something to do you the biome.

Comment: Would *you* consider a room with a werewolf in it valid housing?

Comment: Before this gets closed as a dupe.. Rebuild the room break a part put it back in.. I think there is a bug in 1.3 with this that has not been officially identified where the house gets marked invalid for some reason, rebuilding it has so far worked but no. Those houses SHOULD be valid so its not the normal 'why isnt this working' issue you will be marked as a dupe of.

Comment: @james looks to me like there's Crimson spreading from the right, it's probably a case of those houses being too close to it now. Which means it's a dupe

Comment: @JonK I do not see the cirmson but on that small of a picture and my red/green colorblindness I will assume I am in the wrong here.. I have however had numerous houses just switch themselves to 'invalid' on a load for no reason as far as I have found.. Breaking an outline piece and putting it back has fixed it and then they stay ok.. I am not sure if it was a version update I hopped over that might have snafu'd it or what not, but I was not near any crimson for that to explain what I have seen.

Comment: @JonK Just with out being able to repeat its occurrence I can not say exactly what is the cause.

Answer (score 4):

From your items I can see that you're in hardmode, a common reason for a valid housing to become invalid is because of the spreading of corruption/crimson.

If a room is within ~42 blocks of corruption/crimson, that house becomes invalid housing for NPC's.

You can purify nearby corruption/crimson and see if that makes the house valid. If it does I would recommend preventing it from being able to spread towards your house again. You can do this in multiple ways, such as planting hallow at your house or making a 3 wide gap of non-corruptible material.